# Bundling and Minification in Release Mode deploys source code

Tags: asp.net, deployment, minify

Using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web

Set up bundling and caching as generally described here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

In the VS Solution Explorer, individual file properties for .js and .css files are set to Build Action:  Content.  I don't know if this was specifically set or a default setting.

When deployed in Debug Mode, individual files are deployed to the destination server's directory structure as expected and the rendered code in the index.aspx head section has a long list of  for each individual javascript and css file configured, again, as expected.  When loaded, I can see that the files are being loaded individually.  Everything works.

When deployed in Release Mode, however, individual files are still being deployed to the destination server's directory structure, non-bundled and non-minified.  Index.aspx DOES reflect a rendered reference to each bundled "file" using .  When loaded, I can see that things are being loaded via the bundle.

In Release Mode, the individual files deployed to the destination server's directory structure seem to be redundant, and certainly unwanted.  However, if I remove them post-deploy I get reference errors.  Similarly, if I change file properties for each file's Build Action:  Content to Build Action:  None, the aforementioned individual files aren't deployed in Release Mode OR Debug Mode and I get reference errors in both scenarios.

Question 1:  Am I misunderstanding how bundling and minification works and these individual non-bundled, non-minified files are indeed required in Release Mode?

Question 2:  If I understand correctly that these non-bundled, non-minified files are NOT necessary in Release Mode, how do I configure the deploy correctly such that they ARE deployed in Debug Mode and ARE NOT deployed in Release Mode AND I get no reference errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1: Bundling and minification are done at run-time, not at build, compile, or deploy time. The "bundle" that is downloaded is a virtual file, it doesn't actually exist anywhere on disk. Thus the original "source" files are needed.

Answer 2: Sorry but your understanding is not correct. The non-bundled/minified files are required in Release mode as they form the basis for creating the bundled/minified payload that is sent to the client.